# Confused with using method reference in Comparator.comparing()

Tags: java, methods, comparator, method-reference, functional-interface

Am a self learning developer, now learning Java. I have learned that to use method reference for a Functional Interface, **the signature of the method we referring must match the signature of the abstract method inside that functional interface**.

But While learning Comparator, found that
"Comparator.comparing()" method takes Function interface and returns a Comparator.
**I know that the abstract method of Function interface must take a argument and return a value.**

but I can able to pass any method(as method reference) that partially **(not fully) matches the signature of Function interface** to the comparing() method of Comparator.

for example consider the below example.

```
public class Movie {
private  String title;
private int likes;

public Movie(String title, int likes) {
    this.title = title;
    this.likes = likes;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}

public int getLikes() {
    return likes;
}
}

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {     
    var movies=List.of(
      new Movie("b", 20),
      new Movie("c", 30),
      new Movie("a", 10));

    var stream=movies.stream().
    sorted(Comparator.comparing(Movie::getTitle));  
    stream.forEach(m->System.out.println(m.getLikes()));
  }
}
```

Here, in the line `sorted(Comparator.comparing(Movie::getTitle))`

as you see **the `getTitle()` method takes no argument and returns a `String`**. But it can be **used as method reference** for the **function interface (which takes a argument and returns a value)**.

Why is it happening ? Please answer anyone to solve my confusion.

Comment: "*I know that the abstract method of Function interface must take a argument and return a value*" This is either wrong, or you're not expressing yourself precisely. [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) is a functional interface and it neither takes an argument nor returns a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class `Movie`, `getTitle()` is an instance method. It therefore takes one argument, namely an argument of type `Movie` (the implicit parameter). To call method `getTitle()`, you need a target object:

```
movie.getTitle();
```

Here the object referenced by `movie` is that one argument.

The function type of `getTitle()` is thus `Movie -> String`, which matches the expected functional interface.

Comment: So, you are saying that whenever we make reference to instance methods there is an another argument under the hood?